# Importing an existing website to Google Apps for my domain or Google Sites

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites

I use my own domain for email and have a website hosted there - mainly for sharing family photos etc.

I would like to save money and not pay for hosting on that domain anymore... and importing the data to Google would seem the simplest approach - as I use GAYMD for the email now.

Is this feasible?
There doesn't seem to be an inbuilt option to do it directly, as Google Sites are a little limited, but wondered if there was a several step approach to import the images and then set-up a new structure?

Comment: It has been a while, but since you answered your own question, can you mark it as best answered? Is your answer still the best (and only one...)?

Comment: It is the only answer, but even with that low standard to meet - it's not the best. My personal site languishes on my hard drive still.

Answer (score 1):

No obvious quick route has emerged, but this can be worked through in stages.

- Copy the existing website to local storage
  This may be necessary if you are losing the original website, or wish to redirect to google sites later.
  [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) is one tool that can be used for this. You may need to disable checks on robots.txt file and tell HTTrack to follow all links on your copied site.
- Stage 2
  Still in progress. Trying to find the best route for my website.